# node.js & Bootstrap Workflow -- IDE?

Tags: node.js, ide

I'm an embedded design guy slinging C & Assembly on a microcontroller day in and day out.

I'm coming from writing HTML & CSS in Dreamweaver back in 2008....

I need to update a website, and am taking a course in the most recent workflow using  Bootstrap & node.js (w/ git).

Obviously, I could use notepad... but what are folks using for an IDE when using node.js and also using HTML?  My course is using Visual Studio, which seems like overkill.

Sorry, I'm ten years out of the loop on the tools here.

Answer (score 1):

I find VS Code to be an excellent IDE for node.js applications. It has HTML syntax highlighting and enough extensions to do what you could ever want. The built in debugger is why I choose it over Atom or Sublime Text.

Comment: Appreciate those references.  Seriously, I have no idea where to start.  Saves me a ton of time trying to suss out.  I was thinking netbeans as a starting point, clearly not the case....

Comment: When I was doing game development with C++ I used Visual Studio (Full). I have tried it for node apps. You are right it is overkill. Give VS Code a shot. I also really like the vim extension.

Comment: Wow, and VS Code supports php debugging (I've been using PhpEd for like a million years since 2008).  And it's free... cripes, what a deal.

Comment: Microsoft updates it constantly and there is a large community of great extension developers. The only thing I can knock is that it's an Electron app, but that is probably why it is so quickly iterated on. If I have to open a massive file, I tend to use vim instead.

Comment: Haha... Electron, had to look that up.  I'm a frigging dinosaur.